# ggplot2 multiline title, different indentations

Tags: r, ggplot2, indentation, figures

I am generating graphs for a publication and I'd like to be able to label the panels of a figure in ggplot itself (as opposed to exporting to publisher, etc) so that they just fit neatly together in the final document. I was going to try to do this by adding a letter ("A") into the title, but I'd like my titles centered and I'd like the letter in the upper lefthand corner.

`# base graph:`

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species))+
  geom_jitter(size = 6.5)+
  ggtitle("A \n \n The Actual Long, Normal Title of Titliness")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 30),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 25),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 25, vjust = 0.05),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: oh noes! both of them are centered over the graph]

Now, if I'm willing to just "fake it" by hand-spacing each title, I can sort of get it to work, but this seems time intensive and crude.

```
# sloppy solution
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species))+
  geom_jitter(size = 6.5)+
  ggtitle("A \n \n             The Actual Long, Normal Title of Titliness")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0,face = "bold", size = 30),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 25),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 25, vjust = 0.05),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: better spacing but sloppy code]

Is there a way to call each 'line' of the title individually for an hjust value of its own?

Any other creative solutions?

Also, I saw potential in mtext ([Splitting axis labels with expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985222/splitting-axis-labels-with-expressions)), but couldn't figure out how to implement it with ggplot2 (vs base plot function.. it seems like they're not compatible).
This post was all sorts of interesting ([Multi-line ggplot Title With Different Font Size, Face, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367095/multi-line-ggplot-title-with-different-font-size-face-etc)), but I am still new to R and I couldn't figure out how to edit this clever stuff to change **indentation**.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) may be what you need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update: Since ggplot2 3.0.0 there is now native support for plot labels, [see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480611/4975218)**

Here is how I would do it, using the cowplot package that I wrote specifically for this purpose. Note that you get a clean theme as a bonus.

```
library(cowplot)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 3.5) +
  ggtitle("The Actual Long, Normal Title of Titliness")

# add one label to one plot
ggdraw(p) + draw_plot_label("A")
```

[image]

```
# place multiple plots into a grid, with labels
plot_grid(p, p, p, p, labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

You then want to use the `save_plot` function to save plots instead of `ggsave`, because `save_plot` has defaults and parameters that help you get the scaling right relative to the theme, in particular for plots in a grid.

Comment: With `ggplot2 3.0.0` you can do this with a built in feature. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480611/3277050)

Answer (score 10):

Since `ggplot2 3.0.0`, [there is a native way to do this, using the `tag` label](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.0.0):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "The Actual Long, Normal Title of Titliness",
       tag = "A")
```

[image: ggplot_tag]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to use a title and a subtitle,

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species))+
  geom_jitter(size = 6.5) +
  labs(title = "A", subtitle = "The Actual Long, Normal Title of Titliness") +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: This is simple and lets me call hjust individually as requested -thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grid.text` from package `grid`, add text to your plot. Firstly add some space above your title use `plot.margin`.

```
library(grid)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species))+
geom_jitter(size = 6.5)+
ggtitle("The Actual Long, Normal Title of Titliness")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0,face = "bold", size = 30),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 25),
      axis.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"),
      axis.text = element_text(size = 25, vjust = 0.05),
      legend.position = "bottom", 
      plot.margin = unit(c(4, 3, 1, 1), "lines"))
p
grid.text('A', x = unit(0.1, 'npc'), y = unit(.90, 'npc'), gp = gpar(fontsize=28))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by manipulating Grobs. Using `gtable` and `grid` on top of `ggplot2`.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("gtable")
library("grid")

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, shape = Species))+
  geom_jitter(size = 6.5)+
  ggtitle("The Actual Long, Normal Title of Titliness")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 30),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 25),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 25, vjust = 0.05),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.margin = unit(c(4, 1, 1, 4), "lines"))  # We need bigger top/left margins to show the letter

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))  # Building a gtable from the ggplot object
# Adding the textGrob for the panel letter
panel_letter = textGrob("A", x = 0.5, y = .9, 
                        just = c("left", "top"), 
                        gp = gpar(fontsize = 40, col =  "black", face="bold"))
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, panel_letter, t=1, l=1, r=1)  # Append the Grob to the table

p <- grid.draw(gt)  # Display the plot
ggsave("plot.png",gt, width=10, height=10)  # If you want to save it.
```

[image: My attempt]